# terminal command in python not working

Tags: python, macos, terminal

So, I'm trying to do a simple ping command in macOS using python. My code isn't getting me any errors, but it also isn't actually running a command in the terminal. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
import os

os.system("ping 32 192.168.1.1")
```

Comment: Try `subprocess.check_output("ping 32 192.168.1.1", shell=True)`

Comment: How do you determine that nothing runs? Starting Python in a terminal and typing in these commands produces the expected output. However, `os.system()` is not a good way to do this (see previous comment, though I don't believe it will solve your problem per se) and will appear to hang while `ping` runs; if you run this in an IDE, you probably don't see standard output anywhere useful. `ping` only runs `ping`, it doesn't run a terminal instance (nor do Python or `os.system` unless you separately ask them nicely).

Comment: ok, thanks. It turned out that it was running stuff in the background, I just couldn't see any actual output.